# How do I install Google Pixel Launcher on HTC U Ultra?

Tags: launcher, 8.0-oreo, google-now

I used to be able to use the [Google Now Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher&hl=de) on my old HTC U Ultra device. Now I got a new device with Android 8.0.0 and here I cannot install the program anymore. How can I fix that?

Edit: I learned, that Google Now Launcher was replaced by Google Pixel Launcher which is not available on Play Store on this phone but can be downloaded from [apkmirror.com](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/pixel-launcher/pixel-launcher-8-1-0-4429924-release/).

Comment: Google stopped google now launcher and current default launcher by google is pixel launcher. You can download google now launcher from apkmirror, and try to install it. I don't think it may work well, but you can have a try (https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-now-launcher/ dec 6,2017 build).

Comment: I see, then I would like to try Pixel Launcher. Can you post the link to it in the Play Store?

Comment: you can search for pixel launcher from the same site(apkmirror.com). Download apk that suits your android version, architecture, screen DPI. https://www.apkmirror.com/faq/ this link may help you to find right apk for your device from apkmirror website.

Comment: Worked for me, if you copy the link to it from my edited post, I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Google Now Launcher was Google's first public launcher, and it was shipped on Nexus phones as well as millions of other devices, which was a simpler launcher for Android Ecosystem.
- The Google Now Launcher is now listed as incompatible with almost every Android device in Play store.
- Google announced retirement of Google Now launcher in Feb 2017.
- The current default launcher by Google is Pixel Launcher, which released for Pixel devices.

You can download google now launcher from apkmirror website, and try to install it. The last build available is of Dec 6, 2017 [[link]](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-now-launcher/).

- Pixel launcher is available on Play Store, but not available for every devices(mostly for pixel devices). But, you can download Pixel Launcher from this [link](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/pixel-launcher/pixel-launcher-8-1-0-4429924-release/).

Download apk from apkmirror website which suits with your device's  android version, architecture, screen DPI. This [FAQ](https://www.apkmirror.com/faq/) link may help you to find right apk for your device from apkmirror website

Answer (score 2):

If I'm getting correct, here is the direct download link of it through [apkmirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/pixel-launcher/pixel-launcher-8-1-0-4429924-release/pixel-launcher-8-1-0-4429924-android-apk-download/download/), you only need to confirm it when pop up comes from your download manager.

Above one is latest version of Google Now Launcher and it was lastly updated in Nov,2017. Since then no official updates from Google.

There could be another solution to your problem. If you have any problem downloading by searching here and there, you can avoid it and simply download it from playstore on any operable/compatible device then share it to your phone through any 'Sharing App'.