# Install Google Phone dialer on other phones

Tags: applications, huawei, google-apps, default-applications, phone-app

As you know Google Pixels and Nexuses are using [Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer) application as default dialer. and other phones can't install it.

even if we get different versions of it from [ApkMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-phone/), it does not install on phone!

I tested it on Huawei Nova

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205419/how-do-i-install-google-pixel-launcher-on-htc-u-ultra/205457#205457 please go through my answer, its about pixel launcher, similarly try with Google dialer app

Comment: So it means that can not install Phone app?      But why I could install Messages and Contacts from Google product.